# Format in the READ statement and real number rounding

Tags: format, fortran

I am trying to use the format statement in FORTRAN 77 in order to define to precision with which I want to read a number.

Here are the lines of my code:

```
double precision x,y,z   
open(u,FILE='points.dat',STATUS='OLD')    
do 10 i=1,n    
read(u,100) x,y,z    
write(*,*),'check', x,y,z    
enddo   
100 format(3(2x,D14.2))     
close(u)
```

I tried to read these numbers:  1.0542095e-03  -3.4176819e-02  -1.3796906e-01
with different format and the results are:

```
format(3(2x,E14.2)):  check  0.0010542095 -0.034176819 -0.13796906    
format(3(2x,E14.7)):  check  0.0010542095 -0.034176819 -0.13796906     
format(3(2x,D14.7)):  check  0.0010542095 -0.034176819 -0.13796906
```

I would have expected the first line to give 0.001000000 and the second line to give 0.001054209 but it seems that format statement has no effect in the reading or maybe I did not use it properly. Anyone could explain me the effect of the format in the read function and how to use it properly?

Comment: There are two parts to this question, possibly.  The main answer is that the read is doing exactly what it should (when you have a decimal symbol in the input value the width of the decimal part from the format is ignored).  Which leads to: do you also want an answer which tells you have to truncate the value of the correctly read real value to a given number of decimal places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `.2` part of the edit descriptor when reading. Never. It does very bad and confusing things. Always put there `.0`.

What it actually does is that it does nothing at all when the number being read contains a decimal point. So far so it is good. But if the number does not contain a decimal point it will add one according to your number.

So if you read

`'1'`

using

```
read '(E10.2)', x
```

`x` will become `0.01`.

If you read `'1.0'` using the same, it becomes `1.0`.

It is so confusing that I highly suggest to use `.0` in the real edit descriptors under all circumstances.

---

For rounding your numbers you could, for example, do

```
read '(E10.0)', x
x = aint(x*100)/100
```

Comment: Can you comment on why does it behave like that? How does the "read" function works, such that the ".2" part is ignored? Is this not unwanted behaviour? Or maybe link to a reference on it, most online references I've seen do not explain the intended usage of the format on the read.

Comment: @rmhleo This is a very complex topic. You must study the whole chapter of some textbook. https://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html  There are situations where you do want that behaviour, but it is not very common.